# How to show the pages where references were used in the bibliography?

Tags: hyperref, natbib, back-referencing

Is it somehow possible to show the numbers ob those pages in the bibliography, where a certain reference was used? This could be comparable to the glossary.

For example I used `\cite{me2012}` on pages 1 , 3 and 12, then the reference should show:

> me (2012). unimportant paper, no name journal, 1(1):1-15; cited on: 1, 3, 12

or:

> me (2012). unimportant paper, no name journal, 1(1):1-15; 1, 3, 12

instead of

> me (2012). unimportant paper, no name journal, 1(1):1-15

Comment: Use the option `backref=true`.

Comment: This seems to work only for the biblatex-package. Is there something similar for the natbib-package?

Comment: Your question is tagged with `biblatex` and there is no minimal working example showing natbib. However the option `backref` is also provided by hyperref. See: http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html

Comment: updated link: https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `hyperref`. This package provides the option `backref` with is [explained as](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

> In addition, the `hyperindex` option (see below) attempts to make items
> in the index by hyperlinked back to the text, and the option `backref`
> inserts extra ‘back’ links into the bibliography for each entry.

So you can use:

```
\hypersetup{backref=true}
```